# memcpy leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, c, memcpy

I'm converting someone else's C++ to (Objective) C, but I'm having a problem with `memcpy`. I use it as follows:

```
memcpy((void *)virtualFlash[virtualFlashAddress], data, dataLength);
```

The variables are defined as follows:

```
unsigned char virtualFlash[5 * 1024 * 1024]; // 5MB
NSUInteger virtualFlashAddress; // set to 8 later on
unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *)[recordData bytes]; // recordData is an NSData object
NSUInteger dataLength = [recordData length]; // same NSData object
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line of the memcpy. I debugged `recordData`, which returned `<d8ffbd27 2000b1af 1c00b0af 2400bfaf>`, and dataLength, which returned 16--both correct.

`memcpy((void*)virtualFlash[8], data, 16);`

This crashes. I've read that `memmove` works sometimes, but not in my case (same EXC_BAD_ACCESS). I'm unsure what to do, as this is almost exactly copied from the C++ program in which it works fine. My knowledge of C is very minimal, so I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: It's likely the 5MB allocation for `virtualFlash` on stack failed which is undefined behaviour. Were you able to confirm this doesn't happen?

Comment: Don't know Objective-C, but in C, `virtualFlash[8]` would be a `char`, and if you cast that to `void*`, you get an address god knows where. Didi you mean `(void*)&virtualFlash[8]` perhaps to copy into the `virtualFlash` array?

Comment: I'm not sure if Objective-C supports `virtualFlash + 8` but this is probably the simplest way of starting your copy at an offset from the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried `&virtualFlash[virtualFlashAddress]` or `virtualFlash + virtualFlashAddress` already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned char virtualFlash[5 * 1024 * 1024]; // 5MB
```

Your stack may or may not be large enough to accomodate a 5MB allocation.  Even if it is, that's really pushing it a bit and I would allocate that amount dynamically.
Next problem:

```
(void *)virtualFlash[virtualFlashAddress]
```

`virtualFlash[virtualFlashAddress]` returns a `char`, unlikely to be a valid address.  Seems like you meant to write:

```
virtualFlash + virtualFlashAddress
```

Where `virtualFlashAddress` is an offset applied to the base address `virtualFlash` (i.e., the address of the first element in the array).

The name `virtualFlashAddress` is confusing as it is being used as an index into that array, but that's my best guess without seeing more code.

Comment: Ah yes, the & was indeed missing... I didn't fix the 5MB problem, but it doesn't crash anymore either. Is this something I should look at regardless?

Comment: Default stack size for the main thread is 8MB on OS X (I don't remember the default size for iOS); while a 5MB buffer won't necessarily cause a crash, it is rather large to be putting on the stack.

Comment: Alright, I see how that can be a problem then, will look into it. Thanks all for the quick help!

Comment: @StephenCanon: I didn't realize it was that large by default on a commonly used platform.  I'll back down the wording a bit, thanks.

Comment: 8MB on the main thread, really tiny on secondary threads and queues.  Don't back down on the wording.   The stack should *never* be used for allocations of that size.

Comment: @bbum: Oh yeah, I left that in, I just removed the "5MB is likely larger than your stack size on most platforms".  That was apparently wrong.